# Data not getting from table on foreign key on unique field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have table mwallet_terminal_store_mapping in which tid (character varing) is the primary key and  foreign key referring to a column tid in terminal_master. 
In terminal_master, tid (which is character varing)is unique key. and its PK id is long.

Now I have DTO for the first table mapping_details, which is defined as follows.

```
    private TerminalMaster terminalMaster;

    @OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="pine_tid", referencedColumnName = "tid")
public TerminalMaster getTerminalMaster() {
    return terminalMaster;
}

public void setTerminalMaster(TerminalMaster terminalMaster) {
    this.terminalMaster = terminalMaster;
}
```

Schema for the first table:

```
 CREATE TABLE mwallet_terminal_store_mapping
 (
pine_tid character varying(8) NOT NULL,
pine_sid bigint NOT NULL,
pine_mid text NOT NULL,
fis_tid text NOT NULL,
fis_sid text NOT NULL,
fis_mid text NOT NULL,
date_created timestamp without time zone,
date_modified timestamp without time zone,
created_by text,
modified_by text,
status text,
rfu1 text,
rfu2 text,
rfu3 text,
rfu4 text,
rfu5 text,
CONSTRAINT mwallet_terminal_store_mapping_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pine_tid),
CONSTRAINT fk_mwallet_terminal_store_mapping_pinesid FOREIGN KEY (pine_sid)
    REFERENCES store_master (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT fk_mwallet_terminal_store_mapping_pinetid FOREIGN KEY (pine_tid)
    REFERENCES terminal_master (tid) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
    )
```

Schema for the second table:

```
CREATE TABLE terminal_master
(
id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('terminal_master_seq'::regclass),
tid character varying(8),
store_master_id bigint,
status integer,
inserted_on timestamp without time zone,
modified_on timestamp without time zone,
offline_floor_limit character varying(20),
enable_redeem integer DEFAULT 1,
enable_load_activate integer DEFAULT 1,
enable_offline integer DEFAULT 1,
enable_balance_enquiry integer DEFAULT 1,
enable_format_validation integer DEFAULT 1,
enable_category_validation integer DEFAULT 1,
enable_category_popup integer DEFAULT 1,
enable_prepaid_load integer DEFAULT 1,
enable_prepaid_reload integer DEFAULT 1,
rfu1 character varying(20),
rfu2 character varying(20),
rfu3 character varying(20),
block_status integer DEFAULT 0,
enable_gf_redeem integer DEFAULT 0,
externalid character varying(15),
fis_tid text,
licence_id text,
CONSTRAINT terminal_master_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_terminal_master_1 FOREIGN KEY (store_master_id)
  REFERENCES store_master (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT uq_terminal_master_1 UNIQUE (tid)
)
```

Now the problem is when I try to perform search in the first table on the basis of tid,

It says SQLGrammer Exception, because operator does not exist: character varing = bigint.

which means its still trying to compare my string with primary key of terminal_master, 
not tid of which I refereed.

Please clarify.

Comment: Can you show the related part of your schema, since your explanation is not very clear.

Comment: Of what type is column `pine_tid` ?

Comment: I have edited, Pine_tid is of type character varying. I guess mapping in DTO needs some changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here TerminalMaster entity has 'ID' is primary key so your mapping would be like this

```
    private TerminalMaster terminalMaster;

    @OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="pine_tid", referencedColumnName = "id")
public TerminalMaster getTerminalMaster() {
    return terminalMaster;
}

public void setTerminalMaster(TerminalMaster terminalMaster) {
    this.terminalMaster = terminalMaster;
}
```

unique constraint will not be a reference column name.

Comment: but its not mapped to id(primary key) its mapped to tid(unique key). look at the table.